# update sql table fields if field has a higher value then specified

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a column `rank` which contains
`rank

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8`

When I delete number 5 I want the numbers above 5 to go down 1 number. So 6=5 7=6 8=7

`$start_rank = singleSelectQuery('SELECT rank FROM menu WHERE menuID='.$menuID.'');

$update_rank = Query("UPDATE menu SET rank='rank - 1' WHERE partnerID=". $partnerID ." AND rank>".$start_rank['rank']);`

This code does not update the numbers and i do not have a clue what I'm doing wrong:)
Oh, I don't get any errors...
What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**
when i echo update_rank i get:
`UPDATE menu SET rank='rank - 1' WHERE partnerID=1 AND rank>5)`

Comment: see my answer below .. you have 2 mistakes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong : `rank='rank - 1'`

should be

`rank=rank - 1`.

Also the leading `.")"` shouldn't be there at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
update menu set rank=(rank - 1) where rank > 5
```

Comment: @GertKommer: it is working fine, i have tested..Please check once

Comment: you are correct. I'm sorry. it was just the `.")"` that was screwing up the code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming rank is an integer field you shouldn't quote your calculation `rank-1`

```
 UPDATE menu SET rank= rank - 1 WHERE ....
```